# Django: why is _cached_user an instance attribute of request while LazyUser is a class attribute of request?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-sessions

In Django:

```
def get_user(request):
  from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser
  try:
    user_id = request.session[SESSION_KEY]
    backend_path = request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY]
    backend = load_backend(backend_path)
    user = backend.get_user(user_id) or AnonymousUser()
  except KeyError:
    user = AnonymousUser()
  return user

class LazyUser(object):
  def __get__(self, request, obj_type=None):
    if not hasattr(request, '_cached_user'):
        from django.contrib.auth import get_user
        request._cached_user = get_user(request)
    return request._cached_user

class AuthenticationMiddleware(object):
  def process_request(self, request):
    assert hasattr(request, 'session'), "The Django authentication ..."
    request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
    return None
```

As you can see `_cached_user` is an attribute of the instance of `request` while LazyUser() is an attribute of the class of request:

```
request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
```

Why the difference? `LazyUser` basically just checks if `_cached_user` exists and if not then it queries the `session` backend for the user. In that case shouldn't both `LazyUser` and `_cached_user` be attribute of the instance `request`?

Answer (score 0):

```
request.__class__.user = LazyUser()
```

That's because, you can use the logged-in user instance in your views and templates, and the best place to keep that data is request...

On the other hand, **_cached_user** is an inner function of django, that means, that function is used within django, and must be aviod to be used by anyone who uses django. So it is logical not to add this as a class attirbute... As django developers said, attributes started with '_' must not be used for there are written to used within django, not any applicaon written in django.

Also, **_cached_user** check for request, and is some cases, request data of a logged-in user may not contain that information (such as because of browser cache) **LazyUser** guarantees to return a user instance of the logged-in user in every condition.

And Django assumes that the authenticated User associated with a Request will not change during the handling of each web request.